# Dropdown list not populating values from datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdownlistview

I am trying to populate dropdownlist using the following code.  I can see the values from the datatable but dropdownlist only shows the 2 values I loaded (empty text and "NOT APPLICABLE".

```
'Fill method call
Dim ECPDropDownList As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.Cells(Me.ECPColumnIndex).Controls(1), DropDownList)
fillECPDDL(ECPDropDownList, customerNumber)
```

'Fill method

```
Private Sub fillECPDDL(ByVal ddlECP As DropDownList, ByVal customernumber As String)
        Dim founries As DataTable = SOTSOrderAccess.getAllECP(customernumber)
        ddlECP.DataTextField = "ECP_Name"
        ddlECP.DataValueField = "ECP_ID"


        ddlECP.Items.Clear()
        Dim emptyECP As New ListItem
        emptyECP.Text = ""
        emptyECP.Value = ""
        ddlECP.Items.Add(emptyECP)
          

        For Each item As DataRow In founries.Rows
            ddlECP.Items.Add(New ListItem(item("ECP_Name").ToString, item("ECP_ID").ToString))
        Next
End Sub
```

'Function call to get values from database

```
Function getAllECP(ByVal customernumber As String) As DataTable
        Using cnn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("db.connectString"))
            'Need stored procedure to fetch End Customer Project
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SOTS_sel_ECP", cnn)
                Using adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AX_Customer_Number", customernumber))
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    adp.SelectCommand = cmd
                    adp.Fill(dt)
                    Return dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are getting data from getAllECP() as result from database,

try passing parameter this way too,

cmd.Parameters.Add("@AX_Customer_Number", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customernumber;

Comment: I confirm that I am actually getting data back data from the query.  I think the dropdownlist is not being updated when the customer number is passed to the stored procedure. I tried adding:       ddlECP.DataSource = founries and     ddlECP.DataBind() but not working.  Any suggestions how I can make sure the dropdownlist is updated?

Comment: Just an fyi.  I figured out the problem and was able to populate the dropdown list!  Thanks for your assistance!